# ImportError: Interpreter change detected while importing xmlsec

Tags: python, django, python-3.5, xmlsec

I have a Django service and I recently added OneLogin SSO in it.  Everying is working fine on local machine, but on server, login view throws this ImportError on each request.

```
ImportError: Interpreter change detected - this module can only be loaded into one interpreter per process.
```

The complete stacktrace is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.virtualenvs/dj/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/.virtualenvs/dj/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 172, in _get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/.virtualenvs/dj/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 267, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/.virtualenvs/dj/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/.virtualenvs/dj/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 310, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/.virtualenvs/dj/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/.virtualenvs/dj/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 303, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/.virtualenvs/dj/lib64/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "./service/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    from service.apps.onelogin_sso import views as onelogin_views
  File "./service/apps/onelogin_sso/views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from onelogin.saml2.auth import OneLogin_Saml2_Auth
  File "/.virtualenvs/dj/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/onelogin/saml2/auth.py", line 14, in <module>
    import xmlsec
ImportError: Interpreter change detected - this module can only be loaded into one interpreter per process.
```

I am using python 3.5.1 with Django 1.11 and `python3-saml` for SSO.
The machine is on AWS using amazon AMI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out, we are using uwsgi with threads and each thread is creating its own interpreter.
All we had to do is to update uwsgi app's `ini file` to use single interpreter.

```
single-interpreter = True
```